# How to add class A ip subnet to docker0 bridge

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have a dedicated server with one NAT public ip and some /29 ip range is routed to the same server, i want to assign this /29 to docker bridge so that created containers can directly access from one of /29 class A ips

How can i establish dokcer network adding class A ip subnetting to docker0 bridge?

Answer (score 2):

Docker `bridge` network is not bridged to the physical interface, it is NATed.

To achieve what you are asking for in production, use [Pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) or, if you are cutting edge, you can try the [docker macvlan driver](http://hicu.be/docker-networking-macvlan-bridge-mode-configuration) which is, for now, experimental.

Comment: Thanks for the kind response. I did it with macvlan driver. I'm wondering if i can able to bind  single ip to more than one container. is it possible..?